# woocommerce checkbox shipping is not expanding

Tags: checkbox, woocommerce, checkout, frontend

Any ideas why my checkbox from checkout page is not working ? (expanding?)
In Woocommerce settings I have checked Enable shipping and Ship to billing address by default, but i guess my issue is not from here. Do I have to check/uncheck some others to work?
Thanks in advance!

image with the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlPAz.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since the question was originally asked, but I've run into this same problem just recently (I think)--where the checkbox itself doesn't seem to respond to mouse-clicks, but the label for the checkbox does--and fixed it by editing the the code a little bit in the Woocommerce shipping address form template:

At around line 32 of "form-shipping.php", (YMMV) there's the label and below, the check box markup. For some reason, the checkbox (ID="ship-to-different-address-checkbox") doesn't seem to be responding to mouse-clicks properly, but the label is, so I just moved the closing tag of the label (e.g. "`</label>`") to after the checkbox input tag and the checkbox itself "comes alive" on the page....not a "nice" fix, but it works.

Another, potentially more "mainstream" solution is to append the CSS for the check box and bump the z-index up like so:

```
#ship-to-different-address-checkbox{
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
```